# Flutter 'package:socket_io/socket_io.dart' library doesn't exist

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets, websocket

[image]

I tried add the flutter package socket.io but it doesn't exist. I tried add package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart and package:socket_io/socket_io.dart' as IO; libraries but I have a problem. import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; No problems these last two libraries. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Before you can import the package, you must add it to pub. Try the command

`flutter pub add socket_io_client`

This will cause your pubspec.yaml file to update. Then, you can run `flutter pub get` to update the dependencies across your project.